# Styling an unordered list such that a label fits next to it

Tags: html, css

Consider an unordered list such as the following:

```css
.todo__input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.todo-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#bulletPoints {
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-position: outside;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#bulletPoints>* input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo-section">
  <label for="bulletPoints">Todo:</label>
  <ul id="bulletPoints">
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: unordered list]

There are two issues that I have with this result:

1. I would like the first bullet point to be in line with the label "Todo". Currently, it is placed below this label. I don't know if this is possible at all, I would have to move all my input fields up by some space, which I don't know how much it is.
2. I really don't know where this extra margin (marked in orange) comes from. I would like to remove it.

Does anyone have some ideas?

______ update after @TokaLazy's answer ______

This works perfectly when resetting the font-size of my bullet-points to 1rem. I want them to be larger though.

I was thinking, maybe I could just enlarge the line-height of my label, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
label {
    line-height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: a `<label>` element is used to associate a text-label with the relevant `<input>` (or `<select>`, `<textarea>`...) element; how do you want the `<label>` to work here? Should it link to the first `<input>`, the first empty `<input>`, something else..?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "link". The label is supposed to describe all input-fields, or the unordered list if you will.

Comment: I can only really point you towards the MDN documentation for the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element, which is pretty clear as to its purpose/uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can simply add some margin to the top of the label to line it up. If you decide to change the size or position of your bullet points, simply adjust the margin-top on the label to line up accordingly.
2. The "extra margin" is coming from the UL element, just make its entire `margin: 0;`

You also have a `margin-bottom: 10px;` on the input as well. I left that in the example snippit.

```css
.todo__input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.todo-section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.todo-section label {
  margin-top: .7rem;
}

#bulletPoints {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: circle;
  list-style-position: outside;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#bulletPoints>* input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo-section">
  <label for="bulletPoints">Todo:</label>
  <ul id="bulletPoints">
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="todo__input"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the alignment, you can use `align-items: baseline;` on the section.

The margin in orange comes from `<ul>`. Remove it with `margin-bottom: 0;`

```css
.todo__input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


.todo-section {
    align-items: baseline; /** align "Todo" and first bullet */
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#bulletPoints {
    margin-top: 0; /** Replace this by the following row */
    margin: 0 auto; /** It remove margin top and bottom */
    list-style-type: circle;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#bulletPoints > * input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: that's great, it's almost what I want! It works perfectly, if I reset my font-size in `#bulletPoints` to 1rem. I want these bullet points to be larger though.